# Pi 3A+ keeps loosing connection randomly

Tags: wifi, ethernet, web-server, connection, pi-3a+

I'm trying to set my rPi 3A+ as a local server running a docker container that is constantly logging info from a service. (It's running Teslamate)
I've been having trouble keeping it connected to my home network continuously. What happens is that after some random amount of time, usually about a week, it becomes unreachable through ssh until I reboot it.

At first I thought it was the Wi-Fi going into power save mode, so I've added a cronjob to run at boot that turn the power saving off like so:

```
sudo iw wlan0 set power_save off
```

It didn't help, so I thought that maybe it was having trouble with the dynamic IP, so I've set it to a static IP address. It did not help either.

In this stage, since I could not get into it with ssh, I tried plugging a monitor into it to try and do some diagnostics. But right after I plugged the hdmi cable in, I started getting pings again. As if it had just woken up.

The last thing I've tried was to plug it into an ethernet port, using a usb adapter, as I had read somewhere that the Wi-Fi chip might not be very reliable for continuous operation.

As it turns out I just had to reboot it once again.

It is currently running the headless version of Raspbian 10 (buster)

I'm looking for other avenues of investigation to figure out what is going on.

**Update on 2021-04-17:**

I've kept the Pi plugged into a monitor since Apr 12th. It took 5 days for it to loose connection.
When checking the display, I found a wall of the following error message:

```
EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #16001: comm cron: reading directory lblock 0
```

When I connected a keyboard to try to interact with the Pi, it showed new messages saying:

```
Under-voltage detected!
Read-error on swap-device (179:0:2897352)
```

Looking online seems to suggest that this might be a problem with either the power source or a corruption on the sd card.
I've been using a CanaKit power source that came with the pi, so I think it should be safe to assume it is appropriate. However, the under-voltage warning makes suspect it might be at fault as well.
I have another SD card laying around, so I'll give that a try before replacing the power source.

Comment: firstly: *plug it into an ethernet port* ... the 3A+ doesn't have an ethernet port - secondly: how far is the pi from the access point? perhaps the issue is with signal strength?

Comment: @JaromandaX, you're right, I forgot to mention I used a usb ethernet adapter. Also, I've tried multiple places around the house. It currently sits beside the router, so signal strength should not be a problem.

Comment: how about, for testing, you keep a monitor and keyboard plugged in - hopefully, for the sake of debugging this issue, it will lose connection at some point - by the way, I have two 3A+ ... both on 24/7 for months at a time, and have never lost connection

Comment: @JaromandaX , I'll give that a try and will report back.

Comment: This is almost certainly a problem with your network. All of my Pi run for months without reboot.

Comment: @Milliways , thanks for the comment! Any suggestion on what could it be on my network that would cause this? No other device on my network has connection issues.

Comment: @wmaciel Unfortunately not. I suspect this is related to ARP caching. Sometimes pinging an actual IP will refresh cache. Other times only a router reboot works. You could try setting keep alive in ssh .

Comment: @JaromandaX, after leaving the monitor plugged, it took 5 days to fail again, and checking the monitor revealed the following error msg:  `EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): __ext4_find_entry:1532: inode #16001: comm cron: reading directory lblock 0`

I give more details on the main body of the question.